# How do I run my main function in parallel with a multiprocessing.Process without it freezing? (sorry for the sloppy code, I'm new and self taught)

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing

My main function is an app that I want to use for macros, the macros themselves all work as intended, and the function is technically able to work.  The issue arises when you start the function, as you can't interact with the GUI because it is frozen, it unfreezes when the function ends and then the GUI becomes usable again.  Again, I'm sorry about the sloppy and changing code, like I said, I'm self taught and a lot is borrowed and mangled together.

I tried using different start methods like spawn and fork, I tried setting up different ways for the function to end so it wouldn't wait, and at one point the GUI worked but the second I fixed the other bug this one came. I don't have an old save sadly as it was overwritten. There are no errors and I understand that there probably is a solution already out there but I have yet to find it. The code is long 400-ish lines so be warned.

```
from ast import Call
from cgitb import text
from concurrent.futures import process, thread
from itertools import starmap
from logging import PlaceHolder, error
from re import L
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
from turtle import width
import customtkinter
import threading
import multiprocessing
import time
import pyautogui
import sys
import keyboard
label_text="Select counter as well as type below:"
macro_select=0
rand_offset_min=0 #needed to set the variables in case of no entry
rand_offset_max=3

radio_select=0
label_="Please select a macro type:"
dead=False
base_start=";"
customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("System")  # Modes: "System" (standard), "Dark", "Light"
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")  # Themes: "blue" (standard), "green", "dark-blue"
n_process = []
s_process = []
c_process = []
multiprocessing.set_start_method("spawn")

def netherwart(metric_raw):
        y=0
        time.sleep(5)
        print(metric_raw)
        PlaceHolder_0=int(metric_raw)
        while y <= PlaceHolder_0:
            print (PlaceHolder_0)
            print("running")
            print(y)
            pyautogui.keyDown(' ')
            pyautogui.keyDown('a')
            time.sleep(28)
            pyautogui.keyUp('a')
            pyautogui.keyDown('d')
            time.sleep(28)
            pyautogui.keyUp('d')
            y=y+1
        print("flag0")
        


def sugarcane(metric_raw):
        y=0
        time.sleep(5)
        PlaceHolder_0=int(metric_raw)
        while y <= PlaceHolder_0:
            print (PlaceHolder_0)
            print("running.")
            pyautogui.keyDown(' ')
            pyautogui.keyDown('d')
            time.sleep(.25)
            pyautogui.keyDown('w')
            time.sleep(14.5)
            pyautogui.keyUp('d')
            time.sleep(1)
            pyautogui.keyUp('w')
            pyautogui.keyDown('s')
            time.sleep(17.5)
            pyautogui.keyUp('s')
            pyautogui.keyDown('a')
            pyautogui.keyDown('w')
            time.sleep(.25)
            pyautogui.keyUp('w')
            time.sleep(.25)
            pyautogui.keyUp('a')
            y=y+1


def cobblestone(metric_raw):
        y=0
        time.sleep(5)
        PlaceHolder_0=int(metric_raw)
        while y <= PlaceHolder_0:
            print (PlaceHolder_0)
            print("running..")
            pyautogui.keyDown(' ')
            pyautogui.keyDown('w')
            time.sleep(30)
            y=y+1




class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    WIDTH = 780 #set the width of the main gui
    HEIGHT = 520 #set the height of the main gui
    def __init__(self):
        multiprocessing.freeze_support()
        super().__init__()
        self.title("EzFarmerGui") #Naming the program
        self.geometry(f"{App.WIDTH} x {App.HEIGHT}")#Setting the background size
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_closing)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1) 
        self.frame_left = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=self, width=180, corner_radius=0)
        self.frame_left.grid(row=0, column=0,rowspan=4, sticky="nswe")
        self.frame_right = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=self)
        self.frame_right.grid(row=0, column=1,rowspan=1, sticky="nswe", padx=20, pady=10)

        #left frame
        self.frame_left.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize=10)   # empty row with minsize as spacing
        self.frame_left.grid_rowconfigure(5, weight=1)  # empty row as spacing
        self.frame_left.grid_rowconfigure(8, minsize=20)    # empty row with minsize as spacing
        self.frame_left.grid_rowconfigure(11, minsize=10)  # empty row with minsize as spacing | the first number is the actual row or column, row is the y and column is the x
        self.label_1 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self.frame_left,text="Farming Options:",text_font=("Roboto Medium", -16))  # font name and size in px
        self.label_1.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10, padx=10)
        self.button_1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self.frame_left,text="Netherwart",text_font=("Roboto Medium", -12),command=self.netherwart_event)
        self.button_1.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=10, padx=20)
        self.button_2 = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self.frame_left,text="Sugarcane",text_font=("Roboto Medium", -12),command=self.sugarcane_event)
        self.button_2.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=10,padx=20)
        self.button_3 = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self.frame_left,text="Cobblestone",text_font=("Roboto Medium", -12),command=self.cobblestone_event)
        self.button_3.grid(row=4, column=0, pady=10,padx=20)
        self.button_4 = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self.frame_left,text="Settings",text_font=("Roboto Medium", -12),command=self.settings_event)
        self.button_4.grid(row=6, column=0, pady=10,padx=20)

        #Right frame
        self.frame_right.rowconfigure((0, 1, 2), minsize=0,weight=2)
        self.frame_right.rowconfigure(7, weight=10)
        self.frame_right.rowconfigure(3,weight=1)
        self.frame_right.columnconfigure((0, 1), weight=1)
        self.frame_right.columnconfigure(2, weight=0)

        self.frame_info = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=self.frame_right)
        self.frame_info.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="nsew")

        self.frame_options = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=self.frame_right)
        self.frame_options.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2,rowspan=1,pady=10,padx=20,sticky="nsew")
        self.frame_options.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.frame_options.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

        #Configure info
        self.frame_info.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frame_info.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frame_info.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frame_info.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.label_info_1 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self.frame_info,text=label_ ,height=100,corner_radius=6,fg_color=("white", "gray38"),justify=tkinter.LEFT)
        self.label_info_1.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nwe", padx=15, pady=10)

        #Configure options
        self.frame_options.rowconfigure(0,minsize=10, weight=1)
        self.frame_options.columnconfigure(0,minsize=10, weight=1)
        self.frame_options.rowconfigure(0,minsize=10, weight=1)
        self.frame_options.columnconfigure(0,minsize=10, weight=1)
        self.frame_options.rowconfigure(0,minsize=10, weight=1)
        self.frame_options.columnconfigure(1,minsize=10, weight=1)
        self.frame_options.rowconfigure(0,minsize=10, weight=1)
        self.frame_options.columnconfigure(2,minsize=10, weight=1)

        self.radio_var = tkinter.IntVar(value=0)

        self.label_info_2 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self.frame_options,text=label_text ,height=40,corner_radius=6,fg_color=("white", "gray38"),justify=tkinter.LEFT)
        self.label_info_2.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nwe", padx=15, pady=10,columnspan=4)
        self.label_radio_0=customtkinter.CTkRadioButton(master=self.frame_options,variable=self.radio_var,text="Repititions",text_font=("Roboto Medium", -12),value=0,command=self.repititions_event)
        self.label_radio_0.grid(column=0,columnspan=1, row=3,padx=10,pady=10,sticky="nswe")
        self.label_radio_1=customtkinter.CTkRadioButton(master=self.frame_options,variable=self.radio_var,text="Time",text_font=("Roboto Medium", -12),value=1,command=self.time_event)
        self.label_radio_1.grid(column=1,columnspan=1, row=3,padx=10,pady=10,sticky="nswe")
        self.label_radio_2=customtkinter.CTkRadioButton(master=self.frame_options,variable=self.radio_var,text="Experience",text_font=("Roboto Medium", -12),value=2,command=self.exp_event)
        self.label_radio_2.grid(column=2,columnspan=1, row=3,padx=10,pady=10,sticky="nswe")
        self.label_radio_3=customtkinter.CTkRadioButton(master=self.frame_options,variable=self.radio_var,text="Gold",text_font=("Roboto Medium", -12),value=3,command=self.gold_event)
        self.label_radio_3.grid(column=3,columnspan=1, row=3,padx=10,pady=10,sticky="nswe")

        self.slider=customtkinter.CTkSlider(master=self.frame_options,number_of_steps=250,from_=1, to=250,command=self.update_metrics_)
        self.slider.grid(column=0,row=4,columnspan=4,padx=10,pady=20,sticky="nsew")

        #start/stop frame
        self.start_stop = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=self.frame_right)
        self.start_stop.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2,rowspan=1,pady=10,padx=20,sticky="nsew")
        self.start_stop.rowconfigure((0),minsize=10,weight=1)
        self.start_stop.columnconfigure((0,1,2),minsize=10,weight=1)
        self.start=customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self.start_stop,text="Start",command=self.start_event)
        self.start.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=20,pady=20)
        self.stop=customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self.start_stop,text="Stop",command=self.stop_event)
        self.stop.grid(row=0,column=2,padx=20,pady=20)

    


    def start_event(self):
        metric_raw=str(round(self.slider.get()))
        global n_process,s_process,c_process
        if macro_select == 0:
            print("\nStarted")
            n = multiprocessing.Process(target=netherwart(metric_raw))
            n.start()
            print("flag")
            ac=multiprocessing.active_children
            
            print(f'Active Children: {len(ac)}')
            n_process.append(n)
        elif macro_select == 1:
            print("\nStarted")
            s = multiprocessing.Process(target=sugarcane(metric_raw))
            s.start()
            print("flag")
            ac=multiprocessing.active_children
            print(f'Active Children: {len(ac)}')
            s_process.append(s)
        elif macro_select == 2:
            print("\nStarted")
            c = multiprocessing.Process(target=cobblestone(metric_raw))
            c.start()
            print("flag")
            ac=multiprocessing.active_children
            print(f'Active Children: {len(ac)}')
            c_process.append(c)

    def stop_event(self): 
        if macro_select == 0:
            print("\nEnded")
            for process in n_process:
                for process in multiprocessing.active_children():
                    process.terminate()
            print(multiprocessing.active_children)
        elif macro_select == 1:
            print("\nEnded")
            for process in s_process:
                for process in multiprocessing.active_children():
                    process.terminate()
            print(multiprocessing.active_children)
        elif macro_select == 2:
            print("\nEnded")
            for process in c_process:
                for process in multiprocessing.active_children():
                    process.terminate()
            print(multiprocessing.active_children)

    def netherwart_event(self):
        global macro_select
        macro_select=0
        label_="The netherwart macro has been selected."
        self.label_info_1 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self.frame_info,text=label_ ,height=100,corner_radius=6,fg_color=("white", "gray38"),justify=tkinter.LEFT)
        self.label_info_1.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nwe", padx=15, pady=10)
    def sugarcane_event(self):
        global macro_select
        macro_select=1
        label_="The sugarcane macro has been selected."
        self.label_info_1 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self.frame_info,text=label_ ,height=100,corner_radius=6,fg_color=("white", "gray38"),justify=tkinter.LEFT)
        self.label_info_1.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nwe", padx=15, pady=10)
    def cobblestone_event(self):
        global macro_select
        macro_select=2
        label_="The cobblestone macro has been selected."
        self.label_info_1 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self.frame_info,text=label_ ,height=100,corner_radius=6,fg_color=("white", "gray38"),justify=tkinter.LEFT)
        self.label_info_1.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nwe", padx=15, pady=10)
    def repititions_event(self):
        global radio_select
        radio_select=0
    def time_event(self):
        global radio_select
        radio_select=1
    def exp_event(self):
        global radio_select
        radio_select=2
    def gold_event(self):
        global radio_select
        radio_select=3
    def update_metrics_(self, slider):
        global radio_select
        global macro_select
        global xp
        metric_raw=str(round(self.slider.get()))
        if radio_select == 0:
            label_text="Number of repititions: "+ metric_raw
        
        elif radio_select == 1:
            if macro_select==0:
                place_holder=int(metric_raw)
                time_0=int(rand_offset_max+58)
                time_1=int(place_holder*time_0)
                time_1=str(time_1)
                label_text="Approximate time to complete: "+ time_1 +" seconds."
            elif macro_select==1:
                place_holder=int(metric_raw)
                time_0_0=int(rand_offset_max+34)
                time_1_0=int(place_holder*time_0_0)
                time_1_0=str(time_1_0)
                label_text="Approximate time to complete: "+ time_1_0 +" seconds"
            elif macro_select==2:
                place_holder=int(metric_raw)
                time_1_0_0=int(30*place_holder)
                time_1_0_0=str(time_1_0_0)
                label_text="Approximate time to complete: "+ time_1_0_0 +" seconds"

        elif radio_select == 2:
            if macro_select==0:
                place_holder=int(metric_raw)
                xp=int(1334*place_holder)
                xp=str(xp)
                label_text="Approximate experience gained: " + xp +"xp"
            elif macro_select==1:
                place_holder=int(metric_raw)
                xp=int(3341*place_holder)
                xp=str(xp)
                label_text="Approximate experience gained: " + xp +"xp"
            elif macro_select==2:
                place_holder=int(metric_raw)
                xp=int(600*place_holder)
                xp=str(xp)
                label_text="Approximate experience gained: " + xp +"xp"

        elif radio_select == 3:
            if macro_select==0:
                place_holder=int(metric_raw)
                gold=int(30000*place_holder)
                gold=str(gold)
                label_text="Approximate gold gained: " + gold +"gold"
            elif macro_select==1:
                place_holder=int(metric_raw)
                gold=int(9000*place_holder)
                gold=str(gold)
                label_text="Approximate gold gained: " + gold +"gold"
            elif macro_select==2:
                place_holder=int(metric_raw)
                gold=int(3000*place_holder)
                gold=str(gold)
                label_text="Approximate gold gained: " + gold +"gold"

        self.label_info_2 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self.frame_options,text=label_text ,height=40,corner_radius=6,fg_color=("white", "gray38"),justify=tkinter.LEFT)
        self.label_info_2.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nwe", padx=15, pady=10,columnspan=4)
    def settings_event(self):
        self.settings_window=customtkinter.CTkToplevel(master=self)
        self.settings_window.geometry("600x400")
        self.settings_window.title("Settings")
        self.settings_window_options=customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=self.settings_window)
        self.settings_window_options.grid(padx=20,pady=20,column=0,row=0,rowspan=4,columnspan=4,sticky="nsew")

        self.settings_window.rowconfigure(0,minsize=10,weight=1)
        self.settings_window.rowconfigure(1,minsize=10,weight=1)
        self.settings_window.rowconfigure(2,minsize=10,weight=1)
        self.settings_window.rowconfigure(3,minsize=10,weight=1)
        self.settings_window.columnconfigure(0,minsize=10,weight=1)
        self.settings_window.columnconfigure(1,minsize=10,weight=1)
        self.settings_window.columnconfigure(2,minsize=10,weight=1)
        self.settings_window.columnconfigure(3,minsize=10,weight=1)

        self.settings_window_options.rowconfigure(0,minsize=10,weight=1)
        self.settings_window_options.rowconfigure(1,minsize=10,weight=1)
        self.settings_window_options.rowconfigure(2,minsize=10,weight=1)
        self.settings_window_options.rowconfigure(3,minsize=10,weight=1)
        self.settings_window_options.columnconfigure(0,minsize=10,weight=1)
        self.settings_window_options.columnconfigure(1,minsize=10,weight=1)
        self.settings_window_options.columnconfigure(2,minsize=10,weight=1)
        self.settings_window_options.columnconfigure(3,minsize=10,weight=1)

        self.random_offset_lable_frame=customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=self.settings_window_options)
        self.random_offset_lable_frame.grid(column=0,row=0,columnspan=4,padx=20,pady=20,rowspan=1,sticky="nsew")

        self.random_offset_lable_frame.columnconfigure(0,minsize=10,weight=1)
        self.random_offset_lable_frame.columnconfigure(1,minsize=10,weight=1)
        self.random_offset_lable_frame.columnconfigure(2,minsize=10,weight=1)
        self.random_offset_lable_frame.rowconfigure(0,minsize=10,weight=1)
        self.random_offset_lable_frame.rowconfigure(1,minsize=10,weight=1)
        self.random_offset_lable_frame.rowconfigure(2,minsize=10,weight=1)

        self.random_offset_lable=customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self.random_offset_lable_frame,text="EzFarm settings:")
        self.random_offset_lable.grid(column=1,row=1,columnspan=1,rowspan=1,sticky="nsew")

        self.random_offset_lable_frame_1=customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=self.settings_window_options)
        self.random_offset_lable_frame_1.grid(column=0,row=1,columnspan=2,padx=20,pady=20,rowspan=1,sticky="nsew")

        self.random_offset_lable_frame_2=customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=self.settings_window_options)
        self.random_offset_lable_frame_2.grid(column=2,row=1,columnspan=2,padx=20,pady=20,rowspan=1,sticky="nsew")

        self.random_offset_lable_1=customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self.random_offset_lable_frame_1,text="Personalization::")
        self.random_offset_lable_1.grid(column=1,row=0,columnspan=1,rowspan=1,padx=20,pady=20,sticky="n")

        self.random_offset_lable_2=customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self.random_offset_lable_frame_2,text="Randomized offset:")
        self.random_offset_lable_2.grid(column=1,row=1,columnspan=1,rowspan=1,padx=20,pady=20,sticky="n")

        self.optionmenu_1 = customtkinter.CTkOptionMenu(master=self.random_offset_lable_frame_1,values=["Light", "Dark", "System"],command=self.change_appearance_mode)
        self.optionmenu_1.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=20,pady=10,sticky="nsew")

        self.random_offset_lable_2.columnconfigure(0,minsize=10,weight=1)
        self.random_offset_lable_2.columnconfigure(1,minsize=10,weight=1)
        self.random_offset_lable_2.columnconfigure(2,minsize=10,weight=1)
        self.random_offset_lable_2.rowconfigure(0,minsize=10,weight=1)
        self.random_offset_lable_2.rowconfigure(1,minsize=10,weight=1)
        self.random_offset_lable_2.rowconfigure(2,minsize=10,weight=1)

        self.offset_ui_0=customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=self.random_offset_lable_2,width=30,placeholder_text="Insert the min value:")
        self.offset_ui_0.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=2,padx=10,pady=10,sticky="nsew")

        self.offset_ui_1=customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=self.random_offset_lable_2,width=30,placeholder_text="Insert the max value:")
        self.offset_ui_1.grid(row=2,column=0,columnspan=2,padx=10,pady=10,sticky="nsew")

        self.submit_button=customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self.random_offset_lable_frame_2,text="Submit",command=self.submit)
        self.submit_button.grid(row=3,column=1,padx=20,pady=20,sticky="nsew")  
    def submit(self):
        global rand_offset_min
        global rand_offset_max
        
        rand_offset_min=int(self.offset_ui_0.get())
        rand_offset_max=int(self.offset_ui_1.get())

        if rand_offset_min<0 or rand_offset_max<0:
            error_=customtkinter.CTkToplevel(master=self)
            error_.title("Error")
            error_message=customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=error_,text="Error, please enter a whole number over 0")
            error_message.grid(padx=10,pady=10)
    def change_appearance_mode(self, new_appearance_mode):
        customtkinter.set_appearance_mode(new_appearance_mode)
    def button_event(self):
        print("Button pressed")
    def change_appearance_mode(self, new_appearance_mode):
        customtkinter.set_appearance_mode(new_appearance_mode)






    def on_closing(self, event=0):
        self.destroy()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please create a **minimal** reproducible example.

Comment: Oh, bro. Do you even Minecraft? With that aside, welcome to Stack Overflow. You should take the time to read the "How do I ask a good question?" -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Points to highlight here from there would be, a minimal reproducible example (ideally not globs of code) and a heading that is pertinent to the question (you can leave out "(sorry for the sloppy code, I'm new and self taught)") and if you really wanted to include that, mention it at the beginning of your question.

Comment: This question has far too much code. Please follow the advice here: [mcve].

Comment: When you do `multiprocessing.Process(target=netherwart(metric_raw))`, this immediately runs `netherwart(metric_raw)`, and passes the result to `target`. Are you aware of that, and is that your intention?